# Unable to run your project. Please ensure you have a runnable project type and ensure 'dotnet run' supports this project

Tags: .net, api, angular8

I am getting the above error, when I am trying to run the angular 8 with dotnet api code on Visual Studio Code.
The app has 3 parts: Angular part, dotnet API, DAL
When i run the below command in API, the error occurs.
Command: dotnet run
Error: 'Unable to run your project. Please ensure you have a runnable project type and ensure 'dotnet run' supports this project. A runnable project should target a runnable TFM (for instance, netcoreapp2.0) and have OutputType 'Exe'. The current OutputType is 'Library'.'

Answer (score 0):

Apparently,culd not found a viable solution. So I deleted the Web API project and recreated it.  It worked.